# How to check for null from Firebase in data table?

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image: The picture below is my database collection.]I have two documents and in document "1" i have a collection of 8 items and in document "2" i have a collection of 9 items. When i am calling it in a Data Table as show from below i am getting error of null in the document "1" whereas the document "2" i am getting all the fields as defined.

How can i do a loop to check if null do not display any row or any kind of solution to check for null and not to display it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BusInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  BusInfo({@required this.routenum, this.stop1, this.stop2, this.stop3, this.stop4,
  this.stop5, this.stop6, this.stop7, this.stop8, this.stop9,});

  final  routenum;
  final stop1;
  final stop2;
  final stop3;
  final stop4;
  final stop5;
  final stop6;
  final stop7;
  final stop8;
  final stop9;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
            body: DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(routenum),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
                elevation: 3,
                bottom: TabBar(indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label, tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Route Info"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Timetable"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(children: [
                 Center(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    DataTable( 
              columns: [ 
                DataColumn(label: Text('Margeot - Victoria'),), 
              ], 
              rows: [ 

                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop1)), 
                ]), 
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop2)), 
                ]), 
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop3)),  
                ]), 
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop4)),  
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop5)),  
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop6)),  
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop7)),  
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop8)),  
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [ 
                  DataCell(Text(stop9)),  
                ]),
              ], 
              sortColumnIndex: 0,
              sortAscending: true,
            ), 
              ]),
        ),
            Icon(Icons.movie),
          ]),
        ))
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you have 8 bus stops in your first table, and 9 stops in your second one. So to be able to check if your 9th stop is null you would need to do it like this:

```
            DataRow(cells: [ 
              DataCell(Text(stop8)),  
            ]),
            stop9 != null?
              DataRow(cells: [ //this is the code if stop 9 is not equal to null
              DataCell(Text(stop9)),  
            ]): null //this is the code if stop 9 is equal to null
```

Comment: i am getting error **NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'cells' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: cells**